# Selecting value from oi-select dropdown in selenium

Tags: selenium

In my application there is oi-select dropdown which contains dynamic value. I want to select value from dropdown. I tried below code but it always select 1st element in the list

```
for(WebElement skill:selectSkill) {
            System.out.println(".............................."+skill.getText());
            if(skill.getText().equals(expectedSkills)) {
                skill.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you paste your DOM?

Comment: Hi @anshulGupta drodown DOM is difficult to paste because on key event dropdown get closed

Comment: It could be difficult in that case. Are you able to enter in the if loop ? If so ,did you tried doing skill.click(); rather than skill.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); ?

Comment: Thanks.. click() works :)

Comment: Great, do up vote and accept it as a solution. It will help me answering more, motivation factor :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `skill.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);` , use below code-

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of the dropdown here")));
select.selectByVisibleText(expectedSkills);
```

Comment: Sorry above code will not work..because dropdown tag is div which contains dynamic ul and li